# Add text to Windows 8 Search charm menu

Tags: microsoft-metro, winjs, charms-bar

I would like to be able to add some text (not a link) to the Windows 8 search charm menu (*not* a flyout, the menu itself). I'm currently adding commands/links to the menu like this (simplified for this post):

```
WinJS.Application.onsettings = function(e) {
    // inside of a loop...
    e.detail.e.request.applicationCommands.append(
        new Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.SettingsCommand("defaults", theLabel, function () {
            Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(new Windows.Foundation.Uri(theUrl));
        })
    );
};
```

This produces the commands/links I need, but I want to ad some text in there... any ideas? Is this possible?